What type of subfloor should I use to replace damaged particle board?
Our 1987 Horton double-wide has several damaged subfloor areas from water leaks. The subfloor is Georgia Pacific particle board as a single layer floor. The old carpet still goes under the wall plates. I need to replace areas the insurance won’t cover. What thickness and type do I need?

Modern homes are typically built with 3/4" (18mm) class subfloor material. This is typically oriented strand board (OSB) or plywood in a tongue-and-groove configuration. I would use either of those* in your case, and it's not really relevant that you're working on a modular or mobile home. The needs are essentially the same.
* Some will say that OSB is a poor choice, but it's less expensive, more flat and stable, and doesn't fall apart if it gets wet for a short period. It will swell if it's wet for a long time, but so will plywood.
